# Making tabular without frame for text and left justify

Tags: tabulary

I've seen related to this problem, but my problem is the output shows mathstyle with italic font instead of textstyle (Not italic).
And then i tried to use `\text{...}`, but it didn't work and a lot of errors happened.

And what if i get rid the dollar symbol? The tabular will fail.

So, this is my code:

```
\begin{center}
     \begin{tabular}
      $\begin{array}{ll}
       \text{My Name   & : Justin Bieber \\
        Class          & : VIII D \\
        NIM            & : 1234567890}
     \end{array}$
     \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Please help me to fix my code until shows textstyle, tabular set with left justify.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code contains several syntax errors. Don't just blow past them and see if the code will still somehow compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to place an `array` environment inside a `tabular` environment -- at least not the way you are attempting to do it. `array` is mainly for math-mode material; `tabular` is mainly for text-mode material. Your code also generates quite a few syntax error messages -- don't ignore them.

Anyway, here's an attempt to fix your code:

```
\begin{center}
     \begin{tabular}{ll}
        My Name   & Justin Bieber \\
        Class     & VIII D \\
        NIM       & 1234567890
     \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: I'm newbie tbh. So i don't realized i can use this. Thank you very much for the answer!